# Rails polymorphic association link not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

I'm trying to set up a polymorphic association, and I seem to have everything working except this one thing. I'm following along with the railscast here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOFAcbxdWjY and there is a section where he adds a link to a new comment that's linked to the photo.

The code he listed worked in the video just fine. In the video the `[:new, @commentable, @comment]` line makes the link go to `..photos/1/comments/new`

Here is what I have in my `comments` view.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h3>Comments</h3>
    <p><%= link_to "New Comment", [:new, @commentable, @comment] %></p>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <div class="comments">
        <div class="post-title"><%= comment.content %></div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Only thing is that when I do this, the link points to

`..articles/new.4`

instead of `..articles/4/comments/new`

What am I doing wrong? I'm also using rails5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your problem is a typo, you are using `@comment` instead of `:comment`.

Try changing:

```
<p><%= link_to "New Comment", [:new, @commentable, @comment] %></p>
```

to:

```
<p><%= link_to "New Comment", [:new, @commentable, :comment] %></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use the [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) helper, try this out:

```
<p><%= link_to "New Comment", new_polymorphic_path([@commentable, @comment]) %></p>
```